# Помогите составить запрос mySQL с вычислением при условии

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть таблицы:

1. leads со столбцами  `id(int) | date_create(int) | pipline_id(int) |
   main_contact_id(int) | responsible_user_id(int)`
2. notes_calls со столбцами  `element_id(int) | date_create(int) | text(text) | duration(int)`
3. users со столбцами  `name(text) | id(int) | group_id(int)`
4. groups со столбцами  `name(text) | id(int)`

Нужно получить таблицу:

1. столбец - уникальные id таблицы leads
2. столбец - date_create уникального id таблицы leads
3. столбец - Минимальное значение таблицы notes_calls по столбцу date_create, при условии, если в соответствующем минимальному значению столбце notes_calls.text нет совпадений '%ipun%' или '%oizvonk%'. Если совпадения есть, тогда нужно по той же строке с минимальным notes_calls.date_create вычесть из notes_calls.date_create соответствующее значение notes_calls.duration.
4. столбец - users.name
5. столбец - groups.name
6. столбец - notes_calls.text

Составил запрос:

```
SELECT leads.id, 
       leads.date_create,  
       MIN(notes_cal ls.date_create),
       users.name,  
       groups.name,  
       notes_calls.text  
FROM `leads`  
INNER JOIN notes_calls ON leads.main_contact_id = notes_calls.element_id  
inner join users on leads.responsible_user_id = users.id  
inner join groups on users.group_id = groups.id  
where leads.date_create >= 1538341200 
  and leads.pipeline_id = 514933  
  and notes_calls.date_create >=leads.date_create  
GROUP BY leads.id
```

Это почти то что нужно, но к сожалению этот запрос не учитывает вот этого условия по столбцу 3:

> при условии, если в соответствующем минимальному значению столбце
>   notes_calls.text нет совпадений '%ipun%' или '%oizvonk%'. Если
>   совпадения есть, тогда нужно по той же строке с минимальным
>   notes_calls.date_create вычесть из notes_calls.date_create
>   соответствующее значение notes_calls.duration

Я понимаю, что составленный запрос выводит по столбцу 3 лишь то, что я задал, т.е. минимальное значение notes_calls.date_create. 
Как реализовать это условие я пока не знаю, поэтому и прошу помощи сообщества.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при условии, если в соответствующем минимальному значению столбце
>   notes_calls.text нет совпадений '%ipun%' или '%oizvonk%'. Если
>   совпадения есть, тогда нужно по той же строке с минимальным
>   notes_calls.date_create вычесть из notes_calls.date_create
>   соответствующее значение notes_calls.duration

```
SELECT ...,
notes_calls.date_create - CASE WHEN notes_calls.text LIKE '%ipun%' 
                                   THEN notes_calls.duration
                               WHEN notes_calls.text LIKE '%oizvonk%'
                                   THEN notes_calls.duration
                               ELSE 0
                           END AS date_create, ...
FROM ...
```

Вот только нужно в подзапросе получить всю запись и notes_calls - одним MIN() дело уже не обойдётся.

Comment: Очень круто!!! Помогло. Спасибо, большое))))